# Regex notification indicating success/fail

Tags: regex, perl, bash, shell

Is it possible to get some type of notification or indicator that a regex replacement was successful or not?

for example i would like to know if:

```
perl -pi -e 's|\x0a\x00\xde\x10|\x0a\x00\xde\x10|g' somefile
```

found and replaced the given hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 'warn "successful for line $." if s|\x0a\x00\xde\x10|\x0a\x00\xde\x10|g' somefile
```

Notice for every line,

```
perl -pi -e 'warn s|\x0a\x00\xde\x10|\x0a\x00\xde\x10|g ? "yes" : "no"' somefile
```

Comment: nice, that appeared to work. one more question, is it possible to set a variable or bool for the notification. i.e. if success `s=$"YES"` if not `s=$"NO"`

Comment: @user3257552 nema na cemu.

Comment: Please start a new question for python rather than extending existing one